# android studio create new file ,can't resize window

Tags: android

[image]

the window is too big to see the button,that cannot resize the window also,I need some help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, hit the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> combination, then you’ll be able to drag the window using arrows on your keyboard. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after adjusting.

Comment: This doesn't work for me; I can't drag the window high enough to reveal the buttons.  Also, minimize, maximize, and resize are all non-functioning (greyed out in the first two cases).  When I do attempt to resize at the top margin, the window simply jumps down about one inch, taking even more of itself offscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [Movsar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536477/3364905) answer, if you wish to just accept , press enter after you are done with the dialog.  Otherwise click on the cross to cancel the dialog.